# How to fetch the test result and code coverate stats in fastlane to notify else where?

Tags: ios, fastlane

Am using fastlane for my app and right now have configured to generate HTML reports for tests & code coverage.

Is it possible to fetch the stats as seen on command line so that I could use it to notify on separate chat app which I use ?

```
+------------------+---------+
|    xcov Coverage Report    |
+------------------+---------+
| 123456789012.app | 100.00% |
+------------------+---------+

+--------------------+---+
|      Test Results      |
+--------------------+---+
| Number of tests    | 1 |
| Number of failures | 0 |
+--------------------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like [xcov](https://github.com/nakiostudio/xcov) and [gcovr](https://github.com/gcovr/gcovr) to gather coverage data on top of fastlane. Links are as follows to the documentation:

- https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gcovr/
- https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/xcov/

For test results, i believe there is no straight forward answer for that because the logs you see in the console are not directly exposed by Xcode.
When you are running your application, Xcode creates a file called `TestSummaries.plist`, which has all the steps and results.

Some of the developers were in your position, where they ended up writing a macOS application, just to parse the plist and get all the data. Following is the reference to the project.

- https://github.com/nacuteodor/ProcessTestSummaries
- https://github.com/KrauseFx/trainer

Lastly, go through the following article which explains how test logs are structured in the `testSummaries.plist`

- https://michele.io/test-logs-in-xcode/

Hope all the links and explanations help you out. :)